# What are good introductory resources for expert developers new to the .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a client who wants to transition off their old environment into .NET.

The client has a good grounding in basic OO concepts (their existing development environment supports this) and are expert developers, but need a quick "up to speed" introduction to the .NET framework (C# as the chosen language) for building Line of Business applications (they're keen on Silverlight).

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with "How do I?" videos for C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb798022.aspx .

Answer (score 2):

For .Net Frmework

[http://www.amazon.com/CLR-via-Dev-Pro-Jeffrey-Richter/dp/0735627045/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1274297492&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045)

then get to Silverlight
http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/